# Use shell variables in MongoDB query

Tags: bash, mongodb, shell, mongodb-query, zsh

Is there a way to use shell variables in a MongoDB query?

I have this for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mongo --eval "use cdt_db; db.users.update({username:'${USER}'}, {'\$set':{roles:['Admin']}});"
```

I tried single quotes and double quotes, I get this error:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.9
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.9
2017-10-09T13:53:51.747-0700 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell eval):1:4
```

Comment: Shouldn't `$set` be without the quotes? The safest way would be to write the expression under single quotes, concatenating it with variable values: `mongo cdt_db --eval 'db.users.update({username:"'"$USER"'"}, {$set:{roles:["Admin"]}});'`.

Comment: yes that seems to work, if you could add an answer explain in detail, I will give an upvote at the very least

Comment: Glad to hear it. I'll write it up.

Comment: It works with 2 fewer quote chars, like so: `mongo cdt_db --eval 'db.users.update({username:"'${USER}'"}, {$set:{roles:["Admin"]}});'`

Comment: not sure exactly why though...and also, with single quotes, you do not need to escape the $ in $set ??

Comment: the single quote escaping thing I get - but the first thing you said I don't understand. The shell is going to expand `$USER` either way, so couldn't `$USER` be anything, including `rm -rf /`?

Comment: Let me correct/amend myself. The `$USER` undergoes a shell parameter expansion (always, unless single-quoted). So if `USER='*'`, then `"$USER"` will expand to `*`. However, if you don't double-quote it then it also goes through a pathname expansion (globbing), so `$USER` will expand to `file1 file2 ...`. If you write `cmd 'str' $USER`, the variable is pathname-expanded (`cmd` receives `str file1 file2 ...`), but if you write `cmd 'str'$USER`, then the variable is not pathname-expanded (unless has spaces), but spaces in `USER` are not preserved! So the safe thing is to write `cmd 'str'"$USER"`.

Comment: if you could add an answer, that will make you at least 10 points richer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the shell standpoint, your query is fine. Variable `USER` is expanded properly and `$` in `$set` is properly escaped to prevent the shell parameter expansion.

The problem is in your `use <dbname>` part of the query. According to the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#differences-between-interactive-and-scripted-mongo):

> You **cannot** use any shell helper (e.g. **`use <dbname>`**, **`show dbs`**, etc.) inside the JavaScript file because they are not valid JavaScript.

Instead, you can use a JavaScript equivalent:

```
db = db.getSiblingDB('<dbname>')
```

or, better yet, specify the name of the database via command line argument:

```
mongo dbname --eval 'query'
```

Fixed, your query looks like:

```
mongo cdt_db --eval "db.users.update({username:'${USER}'}, {\$set:{roles:['Admin']}});"
```

For convenience (less escaping), you might sometimes also consider using single quotes, and concatenate the expanded variables (under double quotes):

```
mongo cdt_db --eval 'db.users.update({username:"'"${USER}"'"}, {$set:{roles:["Admin"]}});'
```